# Is voice recognition on Android Wear performed on the device?

Tags: voice-recognition, android-wear

The recently announced smartwatches based on Android Wear extensively rely on voice recognition for user interaction.

Is the voice recognition performed on-device, on the paired smartphone, or in Google's cloud? Or is it a mix of those three, e.g. online with an offline fallback?

Answer (score 1):

While I don't have any official source, from testing it's clear that it's cloud based.

- Watch paired, handheld with internet connection -> Works.
- Watch paired, handheld without internet connection (e.g. airplane mode) -> Doesn't work.
- Watch not paired (e.g. handheld turned off) -> Doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

the voice recognition is performed on device; information of the voice is persisted in Google's cloud

Comment: Do you have any sources? What do you mean by "information of the voice is persisted"?

Comment: Most likely our good old "language barrier", and what was meant is "recorded voice data is processed", i.e. audio analysis is done on Google servers. I would wonder if it were different, as this is the way it's done on Android phones/tablets as well (and I doubt Wear devices have more power, so they wouldn't need that).